# A GUI on my almost-fresh Ubuntu Server 21.04 install?

Tags: server, login, gui, 21.04

I installed & set up my Ubuntu Server 21.04 yesterday. Spent the whole day installing packages, configuring everything, and getting everything looking just right.

All of a sudden, my SSH lost connection. I went to the server and it was in sleep mode(???)

I hit the power button, it woke up, and on my screen, instead of seeing the typical CLI login, I saw the GUI login?

[image: GUI Login screen on Ubuntu Server installation?]

Out of curiosity, I tried logging in on the GUI and I was met with the desktop & app drawer search capabilities.

[image: App drawer worked]

One more additional piece of information: One of the CLI apps said I needed to install these packages. Is it possible one of them inadvertently installed a GUI?

`build-essential cmake pkg-config libssl-dev libzmq3-dev libunbound-dev libsodium-dev libunwind8-dev liblzma-dev libreadline6-dev libldns-dev libexpat1-dev libpgm-dev qttools5-dev-tools libhidapi-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libudev-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-locale-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-serialization-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev ccache doxygen graphviz`

**My questions:**

1. How did this happen?
2. How do I remove the GUI and go back to normal?

Comment: Review your apt log. Somewhere along the line, you told the system to install something that needed a desktop environment.

Comment: How remove the GUI is also easy. Uninstall the offending application, then autoremove the desktop stack.

Comment: Thanks @user535733 I just pasted some packages that may have been the culprit. Any of them look familiar?

Comment: Why guess? Review your apt log to see what was actually installed. Pick a desktop package. Simulate removal of that desktop package. The offender will be on the list of proposed removals.